Is there a reason why I can't use find to scan modified files for viruses and malware?
I need to scan Linux systems for viruses/malwares, just entire filesystem. There are few options to consider.

One is normally what users do: Use antivirus to scan system once a day.
The second option is to find files modified in last one day and give that list to anti virus program.

I tested following bash command find on directory with 5 million empty files and it's extremely efficient.
date;find /test/ -type f -ctime -1 -type f 1>./find_ctime.out 2>./find.errors;date
It takes only about 5 seconds.
I am using -ctime option just to overcome some program changing modification time using utility such as touch.
Most admins when they talk about a system scan they talk about having antivirus do the complete scan.
Is there a reason why find should not be used to get list of files modified and scan them?
An aside: This question is posted as https://superuser.com/questions/1864184/is-there-a-reason-why-i-cant-use-find-to-scan-modified-files-for-viruses-and-ma. I am posting it here as well because I am not sure which is the best site for it.
Thanks in advance,

Voting to migrate the question to [unix.se] because it's, well, a Unix question. And FYI, cross posting is not very welcome on most SE sites (including here). If you are unsure where to ask a question pick a candidate and ask in their meta site if it's a fit.

@GeraldSchneider Thanks for the suggestion about meta site. I will remember that. For now, you can move this site you suggested.
